# How to close a sidecart if i click outside of it

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, e-commerce

i am trying to figure out how i can make my sidecart to close when i click outside of it, here is my scirpt:

```
   const toggler = document.getElementById('menu-toggle');
const cartWrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var crossButton = document.getElementById('closeCart');




// Displaying Menu Cart
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    toggler.addEventListener('click', toggleCart);
    crossButton.addEventListener('click',closeCart);
    
    function toggleCart(){

        cartWrapper.classList.toggle('menuDisplayed');
        cartWrapper.classList.toggle('menuDisplayedBgColor');

    }

    function closeCart(){

        cartWrapper.classList.toggle('menuDisplayed');
        cartWrapper.classList.toggle('menuDisplayedBgColor');
    }

   
 

    });
```

toggler is button that opens sidecart
cartWrapper is the sidecart
and crossButton the cross button that close the sidecart

Here is my sidecart:

[image]

If you want more information about my code i would appreciate it if you tell me, Thank you!

My html code:

```
    <!-- Sidebar Cart-->

<div id="wrapper">
  
    <!-- Sidebar -->
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-auto titleCart">
      <h2 class="titleText">YOUR CART</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="left:30%"> 
      <div class="crossIcon" id="closeCart">
        <span class="iconify closeIcon" data-icon="zmdi:close"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
      <ul class="sidebar-nav">

      <li class="cart-item">
        <div class="cart-item-img">
           <img src="imgProducts/guitar1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="cart-item-txt">
           <a class = "cart-item-name" href="#">Miyiagi Guitar</a>
            <span class="cart-item-price-qty">
                1 x 16.00
            </span>
        </div>        
        <button class="button deleteBtn"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="position:relative;font-size:24px; left:0;"></i></button>   
        </li>

      </ul>

    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top:4em;">
      <hr class="dividerLineCart">
      <div class="cart-total">
        <h2 class="cartTotal">Total: $0.00</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 d-flex buttonsCartDiv">
        <a href="cart.php" href="cart.php" class="buttonViewCart"> View Cart </a>
        <a href="#" class="buttonCheckout" style="margin-right:0.5em;"> Check Out </a>
      </div>
    

  </div>
</div>
```

My navbar that includes the button that toggle my sidecart:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md py-3 navbar-dark" style="background-color: rgba(41, 56, 61,0.65);font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
        <img src="Images/charman logo white-trans.png" alt="Logo" style="height:50px;">
    </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="shop.php">Shop</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link" href="guitars.php"  id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Guitars
      </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="electrical-type.php">Electrical</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="acoustic-type.php">Acoustic</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="basses-type.php">Basses</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.php">Contact</a>
      </li> 
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="has-divider" href="#" data-target="#modalRegister" data-toggle="modal">Sign Up
        <span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true" style="float:left;padding-right:0.4em;"></span>
       </a>
      </li>  
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="has-divider2" href="#" data-target="#modalLogin" data-toggle="modal">Login
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" aria-hidden="true" style="float:left;padding-right:0.4em;"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="menu-toggle"><span id="cart-text">Cart</span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" style="transform: scaleX(-1)" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="badge badge-notify">0</span>
        </a>
      </li>            
    </ul>
  </div>  
</nav>
```

Comment: Please, do not use Images to post your code/errors. Copy & Paste your code/errors directly in your question. [Here's why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @AndreaOlivato You have right, i fixed it!

Comment: i was not able to find the tag with ( id="menu-toggle" ) and I have the styling problem with the code. I think your are not using bootstrap. How are you opening the cards? my WhatsApp +1 484 545 8792

Comment: See this my page on Screen width < 600 and the way the menu works. this may help you http://teachers.freecluster.eu/rwd/Technical%20Documentation.html

Comment: @Mehrwarz Oops sorry, i am using bootstrap i am going to add also the part of my navbar

Answer (score 0):

Well you can just click EventListener to the elements opening outside the sideCart.... ! Btw one question here where you want to get clicked.... you just need to add click event listener outside of this cart thing.. and you are pretty much good to go... !

Answer (score 0):

Hope this Code will help you.

```
<script>
    let sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar-wrapper');
    let navbarTogglerButton = document.getElementById('toggler-button');

    window.document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {             
        let clickedArea = e.path[e.path.length-6]

        if ( clickedArea == sidebar || e.path[0] == navbarTogglerButton) {
            cartWrapper.classList.toggle('menuDisplayed');
            cartWrapper.classList.toggle('menuDisplayedBgColor');
        }
        else {             
            cartWrapper.classList.toggle('menuDisplayed');
            cartWrapper.classList.toggle('menuDisplayedBgColor');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It worked but one thing, when i click somewhere inside the sidecart close also the sidecart and i dont want it

Comment: Change the logic of IF condition. if( e.path[1] =  document.getElementById('menu-toggle') || e.path[1] = YourOtherElements )   ....  if you post the code that make easy to answer the question better.

Comment: i added also my html code to help you because i followed your answer but didnt work

Comment: Your code still does not have all contents required.  Where did you define the cardWrapper? If it did not worked le me know please.

Comment: the javascript file that contains definition of cardWrapper is already added, maybe you didnt see it, your idea it worked but not completely because as i exlpained when i click somewhere in sidecart close my cart as well and i dont want this, btw thank you very much for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (cartWrapper.hasClass("menuDisplayed")) {
    $("body").on("click", function() {
           closeCart();
       });
       cartWrapper.on("click", function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
       });
 });
```